# Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata returns null

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I Upgrade EC2 to IMDSv2 and since then some of the functionality of EC2 and I can not use IMD (Instance meta data) class

For example:
I can't get the region name:
`Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.Region`
It returns null,
actually I get null for instance id either:
`Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.InstanceID`

Has anyone encountered a problem? Or know of ways to solve it, or find alternative ways to achieve region and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question,
All you have to do is update the DLL: ADSSDK.core and the problem will resolved, no needed to change code at all.